# Proving that if $\delta(G)=\min\limits_{v\in V}d(v)$, there exists a path of length $\delta(G)$: confusion about construction of path using neighbors

Tags: graph-theory, proof-explanation

In a proof [image: proof] of this statement at some point we say that given $v_0v_1\dots v_k$, a path of maximum length, we can suppose that all neighbors of $v_0$ are in the path. I see how we can add one neighbor $u$ to the beginning of the path but if $v$ has more neighbors how does this work?

A similar argument is used in the second part... And I also don't understand how the second part proves the existence of a cycle of length $\delta(G)+1$. To me it only proves that there exists a cycle of length $\ge\delta(G)+1$

This graph has $\delta=3$ but it's not obvious why every neighbor of $4$ or $2$ is in the longest path:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the fact that $v_0, \dots, v_k$ is the path of **maximum length** to prove the claim about $v_0$'s neighbors. The part where it says "Indeed, assuming that $v_0$ has another neighbor..." is what you're looking for.

As for the second part, the question is probably asking for a cycle of length $\geq$ $\delta(G)+1$. Otherwise, $G=C_n$ would be a counter-example for $ n > 3$.

Comment: Yeah but if $v_0$ has three neighbors $u$, $v$ and $v_1$ that aren't connected between themselves how do you add $u$ and $v$ to the path?

Comment: Let's say that the path with maximum length has length $l$. The argument is that if there is any neighbor of $v_0$ which does not appear in the maximum-length path, one can add it to the beginning of the path. This new path will have a length of $l+1$, which is impossible.
(You don't have to add both  $u$ and $v$. One of them is enough.)

Comment: Consider the graph $V=\{v,v_1,v_2,v_3,w,w_1,w_2,w_3\},~E=\{vw,vv_1,vv_2,vv_3,ww_1,ww_2,ww_3\}$ the longest path has length $2$ and you cannot add all the neighbors of $v$ to it.

Here $\delta=1$ so it's not really a contradiction but if we added the edges $v_1v_2,v_2v_3,w_1w_2,w_2w_3$ then $\delta = 2$ but the argument by itself is insufficient. We can only add $v_1,v_2,v_3$ because the edges $v_1v_2,v_2v_3,v_3v$ exist, which is not obvious

Comment: The longest path has length 3 (e.g. $v_1, v, w, w_1$). In any case, $v_0$ in the statement was chosen to be an endpoint of the longest path, in this case, $v_1$ or $w_1$, all of whose neighbors are already in the path. ($v$ can never be an endpoint to a path of maximum length, so we don't care if all of its neighbors are not in the path of maximum length).